# Why is there a segmentation fault on changing the loop condition?

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am learning about linked lists, and having trouble with the loop to build it. Here is my code that's causing a segmentation fault.

```
struct node {char data[20]; struct node *next;};
struct node *head = NULL, *newNode = NULL, *p;

char temp[20];

while (temp[0] != 0)
    {   
        temp[0] = 0;
        printf("Enter a word: ");
        scanf("%s", temp);

        newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        strcpy(newNode->data, temp);
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
```

When I replace the `temp[0] != 0` with `temp[0] == 0` it doesn't cause the segmentation fault. What is happening here? Why is the same check inverted not working?

Comment: It skips the code that causes the segv?

Comment: `temp` is uninitialized when you enter the while loop, so the condition check results in undefined behavior.  Perhaps a `do`/`while` loop would work better?

Comment: Anyway `temp` is uninitialised and accessing it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also, note that the current use of `strcpy` is very unsafe. If the user enters a string longer than 19 characters then it will overflow both `temp` and `data`.

Comment: @kaylum so is `scanf()`, for the same reason.

Comment: Is your input string longer than 19 chars?